# Why my VS Code intellisense suggests "await" keyword for "i"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

When I just type "i", intellisense changes the character "i" to "awa**i**t", and make that method async. It really bothers me when I code for statement.

It occurs when I program only in C#, not in other languages.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably a suggestion behavior that can be configured. What happens if you click on the "prevent await keyword" label?

Comment: that "i", of label "Prevent await keyword" is a user snippet I added trying to solve this problem. If I click that label, nothing happens. I just thought that if I add "i" as a user snippet, that new "i" snippet would come before "await" snippet. well, still the "await" is the most prioritized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i had the same issue in VSCode and it disappeared when enabling the EXPERIMENTAL feature "Omnisharp: Enable Async Completion" in the settings of the "C# for Visual Studio Code"-extension. (That the feature also has "async" in its name is probably coincidential :). Seems strange to me, maybe a bug.)