# VSCode: How to disable typing shortcuts?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I use VSCode for editing Unity scripts. I have just updated to VSCode 1.65.2.
Before I updated, I was able to type out a for-loop without any problems.
For instance: for(int i=0; i<10; i++) { }, however, now whenever I type the "i<" keys, VSCode auto-adds "async" to my method signature and "await" to the cursor position where I was typing. This is very annoying as I use "i" (i<) for most of my for-loops. Is there a way to disable this feature in VSCode? In addition, I am not sure what the feature is called, so I have not been able to find anything about it myself. I have searched for "Emmet", "Abbreviations", "Suggestions", "Snippets". None of these categories are producing results for me. Even searching for "i<" as a short-code has not produced any results. To be clear, I would like to disable whatever is causing "i<" from converting my method signatures and adding code. If anyone can help with this, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, finally found something that worked.
In File > Preferences > Settings I enabled Omnisharp: Enable Async Completion according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71456230/why-my-vs-code-intellisense-suggests-await-keyword-for-i). This worked for me. Thank you.